# print more than 1 row, Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to echo array,from same table but different id,from db, more than 1 row in Codeigniter.

Model-----------------

```
public function DeviceRowInfo($mobno)
{

  $this->db->select('*');
  //$this->db->where("mobile_no", $mobno);
  $this->db->where("profile_id", $profile_id);
  $pid_device_count_query = $this->db->get("ptt_device");
  if ($pid_device_count_query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
     //foreach ($pid_device_count_query->result_array() as $count_rows)
    // {
        return $pid_device_count_query->row_array();
        echo $row['device_identifier'];
        echo $row['device_os_version'];
    //  }
  }
  else
  {
     return 0;
  }

}
```

Controller---------------------------------------------------

```
public function ViewDevices()
{

     $data['user_device_row']          = $this->security_model->DeviceRowInfo($mobno);
     $data['user_profile_row']         = $this->security`enter code here`_model->ProfileRowInfo($mobno);
     $data['device_count']              = $this->security_model->DeviceCountInfo($mobno);


}
```

View------------------------------------------------------------------

```
foreach( $user_device_row as $devi_row ) 
        {

            ?>

        <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Device Count</td>
    <td><?php echo $device_count; ?></td>
          </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IMEI</td>
    <td><?php echo $devi_row[0]['device_identifier']; ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OS Versions</td>
    <td><?php echo $devi_row[0]['device_os_version']; ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Register On</td>
    <td><?php  foreach($user_profile_row as $devi_pro_row)
               {

               // set default timezone
               date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');

              // timestamp
               $timestamp = $devi_pro_row[0]['registerd_on'];

              // output
               echo date('d/m/Y',$timestamp);

               } ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Logged in</td>
    <td><?php echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"//$devi_row['device_identifier']; ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Active Device</td>
    <td><?php echo  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"//$devi_row['device_identifier']; ?></td>

  </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: describe little bit more

Comment: I try to print a data from database table which has a same key word in different row so i want to print every row of them to my view page.so in my view page will show table depend on row that have the same keyword which search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Model code

```
public function DeviceRowInfo($mobno)
{

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where("mobile_no", $mobno);
  $this->db->where("profile_id", $profile_id);
  $pid_device_count_query = $this->db->get("ptt_device");
  if ($pid_device_count_query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
      return $pid_device_count_query->result_array();
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
   }

}
```

//Controller code

```
public function ViewDevices()
{

 $data['user_device_row']          =       $this->security_model->DeviceRowInfo($mobno);
 $data['user_profile_row']         = $this->security`enter code here`_model->ProfileRowInfo($mobno);
 $data['device_count']              = $this->security_model->DeviceCountInfo($mobno);

 //Load your view here

$this->load->view('your_view_name',$data);
```

}

//view code

```
foreach( $user_device_row as $devi_row ) 
{ ?>

<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Device Count</td>
<td><?php echo $device_count; ?></td>
      </tr>
<tr>
 <td>IMEI</td>
<td><?php echo $devi_row['device_identifier']; ?></td>
```

```
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: this error occur after it was used ,Message: Illegal string offset. i have read that cause it is not see my query as array. where do I set it to be array, at controller or model or do anything to fix it?.

Comment: In controller use `return $pid_device_count_query->result_array();` instread of `return $pid_device_count_query->row_array();`

Comment: your code is helped, Thank you. Sorry for lately tell you. very thank you.